# WKWebView canGoForward always return false swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview, swift5

I have implemented WKWebView everything works perfect. **canGoBack** value changed but **canGoForward** always return false. If I enable force fully then it works but When Any forward url there then I want to enable forward button.

WKWebView doesn't contain **webViewDidStartLoad** and **webViewDidFinishLoad** delegate method so I use **didFinish** method. It work for back button but forward button not working! I already checked StackOverFlow not find solution for WKWebview.

Below is my code:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void){
        buttonConfiguration(webView: webView)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        buttonConfiguration(webView: webView)
}

func buttonConfiguration(webView: WKWebView){
        print("Back", webView.canGoBack)
        print("Forward", webView.canGoForward)
        backButton.isEnabled = webView.canGoBack
        forwardButton.isEnabled = webView.canGoForward
}
```

**Only mention code is related to this question**
Thank You!

Comment: Aren't you supposed to call the `decisionHandler` at some point?

Comment: Use `webView(_:didFinish:)` to make sure that the web page has been loaded.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes I did decisionHandler(.allow)

Comment: Yes I mention I use didFinish. I just figure out if I refresh the screen then it will enable but not automatically like backbutton enable.

Comment: didFinish Method is calling and back button return true false according to the how I interact with the web view but for forward button don't know always returning me false.

Comment: Nobody even knows where you are reading the buttonConfiguration guy.

Comment: buttonConfiguration called in two places didFinish and decidePolicy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can observe the changes in `canGoBack` and `canGoForward` using KVO:

Adding Observer:

```
  self.webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.canGoBack), options: .new, context: nil)
        self.webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.canGoForward), options: .new, context: nil)
```

KVO Observing Changes (Put enabling/disabling button logic here):

```
 override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if let _ = object as? WKWebView {
            if keyPath == #keyPath(WKWebView.canGoBack) {
                print("canGoBack: \(self.webView.canGoBack)")
            } else if keyPath == #keyPath(WKWebView.canGoForward) {
                print("canGoForward: \(self.webView.canGoForward)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Enable `allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures`:

```
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
```

And don't forget to remove the observer in `deinit`.

Comment: first time both button is enable so I need to disable button in didload for first time?

Comment: deinit {
        webView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.canGoBack))
        webView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.canGoForward))
    }
deinit code is right?

Comment: Add those lines before adding the observer in viewDidLoad:  self.< [Back Button] >.isEnabled = self.webView.canGoBack

Comment: @YogeshPatel Same goes for `canGoForward`. And 'yes' deinit code is right.

Answer (score 0):

The delegate method `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)` is not always called when the navigation is finished. Since error could be received for various reasons, you need to listen to any delegate methods provided by `WKNavigationDelegate` where error is returned.

Delegate methods related to navigation error are as followed:

`func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error)`

`func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error)`